# How do I transfer files from my Mac to Samsung Galaxy J7?

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-galaxy

Got a Samsung Galaxy J7 and a Mac (10.12.3) but when I connect my Samsung to my Mac it just charges. I want to transfer an apk file to test (an Ionic2 app). I installed Android Studio and Android File Transfer but my mac still does not recognise the device. Some articles mention drivers but cannot find them on the Samsung website. How can I transfer an apk file to the device?

Comment: Activate usb debugging in the developer mode settings.

Comment: That is already on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] - I needed to change the cable to allow for a full connection. Was not provided with the original.

Answer (score 1):

Transferring files between macOS and Android or any other MTP devices has always been a nightmare. I have tried a lot of apps and was disappointed with the poor support for Android phones on macOS. Either they were too slow, bug-ridden or too expensive. Finally, all these made me sit and write a macOS MTP app for myself.
Well, then I thought to give it to the community.

**OpenMTP | Advanced Android File Transfer Application for macOS** is safe, transparent, open-source and shall be free for a lifetime!

Download latest version of OpenMTP from https://ganeshrvel.github.io/openmtp

GitHub repo: https://github.com/ganeshrvel/openmtp

**Features**

- Plug and Play. No hassles, easy and instant connection.
- Connect via USB cable - Highest data transfer rates.
- Transfer multiple files which are larger than 4GB in one go.
- Select between Internal Memory or SD Card.
- Split pane views for both Local Computer and MTP device.
- Drag 'n Drop, Grid/List views and the other advanced File Manager features are available.
- Safe, Transparent and Open-Source.
- It's FREE and shall ALWAYS remain FREE!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on Developer Options and allowed USB Debugging?

Go to settings -> About Device and look for the Build Number, it may be under Software Info.

K

Comment: USB debugging is on

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the notifications bar and tapping on the USB Connection item. You should get a prompt with a list of methods for how the device is connected to your computer over USB. You might currently be on the "Charge Only" method, so try and change to a different method and see if your device is now recognized.

For more info on USB modes:

https://www.doubletwist.com/help/question/usb-connect-mode/

Answer (score 0):

You can download/install the following software [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) and connect your phone to Mac, now your phone folder will be visible on Mac machine, Hope it helped you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The cable I had was not plugging in the phone. I changed the cable and everything worked.